# Spring mvc - how to display the text values against the codes

Tags: java, spring

I have a email database table with emailAddress and emailTypeCde. There is another table with emailTypeCde and emailTypeTxt.

Now while displaying the ViewEmail jsp page, I want to show the emailAddress and emailTypeText on the screen. How do I do that?

Also on the editEmail page, I want to show the emailType as a dropdown for users to select. The value in the dropdown would come from the 2nd table that has the  emailTypeCde and emailTypeTxt.

Comment: What have you tired so far and where are you failing?

Comment: which spring mvc version u using

Answer (score 1):

Check the Spring documentation for information on the Spring JSP form tags - the ones you're looking for are form:input and form:select